# Error in Loop with pyspark using Databricks

Tags: pyspark

i am trying to do this code, it will list all tables that already exists in Databricks SQL, if it does not exists, it is suppose to create the table. But i am getting the wrong assigment and don't know where:

```
arquivos = dbutils.fs.ls('/mnt/transient/legado/')
tables = spark.sql('show tables')
tables = tables.select('tableName')
#display(tables)

for table in tables.collect():
    tb_name = table['tableName']    
    for arquivo in arquivos:
        file = arquivo.path
        table_name = arquivo.name.split('.')[0]
        
        if table_name == tables.collect():
            print(f'Table exists, {tb_name}')
        else:
            print(f'Table does not exist, {tb_name}')
             df = (spark.read.format('parquet').load(file))
            deltaFile = f'/mnt/refined/{table_name}'
            df.write.option("overwriteSchema", "true").mode("overwrite").format('delta').saveAsTable(f'refined.{table_name}', path = deltaFile)
```

Result:

```
Table does not exist, bi_dw_dim_aprovacao_nao_conformidade
Table does not exist, bi_dw_dim_aprovacao_nao_conformidade
Table does not exist, bi_dw_dim_aprovacao_nao_conformidade
Table does not exist, bi_dw_dim_aprovacao_nao_conformidade
Table does not exist, bi_dw_dim_aprovacao_nao_conformidade
Table does not exist, bi_dw_dim_aprovacao_nao_conformidade
Table does not exist, bi_dw_dim_aprovacao_nao_conformidade
Table does not exist, bi_dw_dim_aprovacao_nao_conformidade
Table does not exist, bi_dw_dim_aprovacao_nao_conformidade
Table does not exist, bi_dw_dim_aprovacao_nao_conformidade
Table does not exist, bi_dw_dim_aprovacao_nao_conformidade
Table does not exist, bi_dw_dim_aprovacao_nao_conformidade
Table does not exist, bi_dw_dim_aprovacao_nao_conformidade
Table does not exist, bi_dw_dim_aprovacao_nao_conformidade
```

Can you guys help?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `table_name == tables.collect()` be `table_name == tb_name` ?

Comment: i get this error: 
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Does that come from the line I suggested you change or somewhere else?

Comment: yes, exactly where you said